# JavaScript: How can I exit webdriver when exception is thrown?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is an example parallel flow js file in selenium website:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var flow = new webdriver.promise.ControlFlow()
        .on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
          console.log('uncaughtException in flow %d: %s', i, e);
        });

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setControlFlow(flow).build();

    driver.get('http://www.google.com');
    driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
    driver.findElement(By.name('btnG')).click();
    driver.wait(until.titleIs('webdriver - Google Search'), 1000);

    driver.quit();
}
```

If an timeout exception is thrown when waiting for title is `webdriver - Google Search`, then the program just console log the error information and doesn't close the window.

How can close window when an exception is thrown, ie. call `driver.quit()`?

Comment: You should use a testing library like Jasmine or Mocha. They have a tear-down method where you can do the cleaning.

Comment: I think It was a bug in older version of selenium webdriver. check your version and also see this thread https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/654 it might help you.